# Python KeyError on second passing of .format()

Tags: python-3.x, format

I'm using .format() to autogenerate a menu. But I also need to format it as users run more tests to indicate those tests are already done.

Example test dict:

```
menuDict = {
    "1":
        {"testDataDict": "testDataDict1",
        "testName": "testName1",
        "testGroupName":"testGroupName1"},
    "2":
         {"testDataDict": "testDataDict2",
        "testName": "testName2",
        "testGroupName":"testGroupName2"
         },
    "3":
         {"testDataDict": "testDataDict3",
        "testName": "testName3",
        "testGroupName":"testGroupName3"
         },
     "4":
    {"testDataDict": "testDataDict4",
    "testName": "testName4",
    "testGroupName":"testGroupName3"
    }
    }
```

Actual code:

```
def menuAutoCreate(menuDict):
testGroupDict = {}
for testNum in menuDict.keys():
    try:
        testGroupDict[menuDict[testNum]["testGroupName"]].append(testNum)
    except:
        testGroupDict[menuDict[testNum]["testGroupName"]] = [testNum]
 #Groups the tests under the group names       

from natsort import natsorted as nt  
testGroupNamesList = nt(testGroupDict.keys(), key=lambda y: y.lower())
#Naturally sorts group names so they look orderly

textDump = " "
i = 0
while i < len(testGroupNamesList):
    howManyLinesEven = 0
    evenList = []
    howManyLinesOdd = 0
    oddList = []

    testGroupNameEven = testGroupNamesList[i]
    textDump += "|{:44}         |".format(testGroupNameEven)
    howManyLinesEven = len(testGroupDict[testGroupNameEven])

    evenList = nt(testGroupDict[testGroupNameEven], key=lambda y: y.lower())
    #If it's an even number, it puts the menu template on the left side of the screen


    if i != len(testGroupNamesList)-1:
        testGroupNameOdd = testGroupNamesList[i+1]
        textDump += "{:45}         |".format(testGroupNameOdd) + "\n"
        howManyLinesOdd = len(testGroupDict[testGroupNameOdd])   
        oddList = nt(testGroupDict[testGroupNameOdd], key=lambda y: y.lower())
    #If it's odd, on the right side.  

    if i == len(testGroupNamesList)-1:
        textDump += "{:45}         |".format("") + "\n"
        #Ensures everything is correctly whitespaced

    howManyLines = max(howManyLinesEven, howManyLinesOdd)
    #Checks how many lines there are, so if a group has less tests, it will have extra whitespaces

    for line in range(howManyLines):
        if line < howManyLinesEven:
            data = {"testNum": evenList[line], "testName": menuDict[evenList[line]]["testName"]}
            textDump += "|({d[testNum]}) {d[testName]:40}    {{doneTests[{d[testNum]!r}]:^8}} |".format(d=data)
        else:
            textDump += "|{:44}         |".format("")

        if line < howManyLinesOdd:
            data = {"testNum": oddList[line], "testName": menuDict[oddList[line]]["testName"]}
            textDump += "({d[testNum]}) {d[testName]:41}    {{doneTests[{d[testNum]!r}]:^8}} |".format(d=data) + "\n"
        else:
            textDump += "{:45}         |".format("") + "\n"
        #Automatically creates a menu

    i += 2

print(textDump)
print("\n")
```

Output of this, as expected:

```
|testGroupName1                                       |testGroupName2                                        |
|(1) testName1                    {doneTests['1']:^8} |(2) testName2                     {doneTests['2']:^8} |
|testGroupName3                                       |                                                      |
|(3) testName3                    {doneTests['3']:^8} |                                                      |
|(4) testName4                    {doneTests['4']:^8} |                                                      |                                                     |
```

This last step will be done elsewhere, but put here for demonstration:

```
    doneTests = {}
for testNum in menuDict.keys():
    doneTests[testNum] = "(-)"        
print(doneTests)

#textDump.format(**doneTests)
#This doesn't work for some reason?

textDump.format(doneTests = doneTests)

#This step will be repeated as the user does more tests, as an indicator of 
 which tests are completed.
```

The expected output would be this:

```
|testGroupName1                                       |testGroupName2                                        |
|(1) testName1                    (-)                 |(2) testName2                     (-) |
|testGroupName3                                       |                                                      |
|(3) testName3                    (-) |                                                      |
|(4) testName4                    (-) |                                                      |                                                     |
```

But here it throws a:

```
KeyError: "'1'"
```

If you remove !r from:

```
{{doneTests[{d[testNum]!r}]:^8}}
```

It throws a

```
KeyError: 1
```

instead.

I tried formatting with !s. Using lists/tuples. Adding and removing brackets. Out of ideas at this point...

Comment: The dict all at the top has `"1"` as key, not `"'1'"` ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner This is true. But the issue just changes into: KeyError: 1
If you were to change {{doneTests[{d[testNum]!r}]:^8}} to {{doneTests[{d[testNum]}]:^8}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried your example.

I used the function `sorted()` instead of `natsorted()` and added the line

```
textDump = ''
```

to initialize the `textDump` variable before the line

```
i = 0
```

As a result I got no errors and got the expected output.

EDIT

Now I reproduced your error. I removed `!r` from `{{doneTests[{d[testNum]!r}]:^8}}` and used integer keys in `doneTests` variable

```
doneTests[int(testNum)] = "(-)"
```

to solve the problem. I guess the origin of the problem is how `format()` method works.

Comment: Oops. Sorry I had a decorator in there, removed for brevity. I'll add the initialization here too. I don't see why natsorted vs sorted change anything though.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I also realized I didn't do
textDump = textDump.format(doneTests = doneTests)

at the end. This was why it ran, but didn't "seem" to work when I turned the keys into integers...

I guess I'll turn the keys  into integers before formatting then.